# PowerShell --- Get Unique Values from PSCustomObject Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting, unique, pscustomobject

```
[{
    "UserDisplayName":  "Test1 User1",
    "UserPrincipalName":  "TestUser1@test.com",
    "License":  "Basic",
    "UserEmail":  "TestUser1@test.com",
},
{
    "UserDisplayName":  "Test1 User1",
    "UserPrincipalName":  "TestUser1@test.com",
    "License":  "Basic",
    "UserEmail":  "TestUser1@test.com",
},
{
    "UserDisplayName":  "Test2 User2",
    "UserPrincipalName":  "TestUser2@test.com",
    "License":  "Basic",
    "UserEmail":  "TestUser2@test.com",
},
{
    "UserDisplayName":  "Test3 User3",
    "UserPrincipalName":  "TestUser3@test.com",
    "License":  "Basic",
    "UserEmail":  "TestUser3@test.com",
},
{
    "UserDisplayName":  "Test1 User1",
    "UserPrincipalName":  "TestUser1@test.com",
    "License":  "Basic",
    "UserEmail":  "TestUser1@test.com",
},
{
    "UserDisplayName":  "Test1 User1",
    "UserPrincipalName":  "TestUser1@test.com",
    "License":  "Basic",
    "UserEmail":  "TestUser1@test.com",
},
{
    "UserDisplayName":  "Test2 User2",
    "UserPrincipalName":  "TestUser2@test.com",
    "License":  "Basic",
    "UserEmail":  "TestUser2@test.com",
},
{
    "UserDisplayName":  "Test3 User3",
    "UserPrincipalName":  "TestUser3@test.com",
    "License":  "Basic",
    "UserEmail":  "TestUser3@test.com",
},
{
    "UserDisplayName":  "Test2 User2",
    "UserPrincipalName":  "TestUser2@test.com",
    "License":  "Basic",
    "UserEmail":  "TestUser2@test.com",
},
{
    "UserDisplayName":  "Test1 User1",
    "UserPrincipalName":  "TestUser1@test.com",
    "License":  "Basic",
    "UserEmail":  "TestUser1@test.com",
}]
```

Here the PSCustomObject array and i want to get list of unique objects in PSCustomObject array, can any one helpme on this?

Here is my expected Output

```
{
    "UserDisplayName":  "Test1 User1",
    "UserPrincipalName":  "TestUser1test.com",
    "License":  "Basic",
    "UserEmail":  "TestUser1@test.com",
},
{
    "UserDisplayName":  "Test2 User2",
    "UserPrincipalName":  "TestUser2@test.com",
    "License":  "Basic",
    "UserEmail":  "TestUser2@test.com",
},
{
    "UserDisplayName":  "Test3 User3",
    "UserPrincipalName":  "TestUser3@test.com",
    "License":  "Basic",
    "UserEmail":  "TestUser3@test.com",
},
```

Comment: You say it's an array of PSCustomObject's, but the data you've posted appears to be json - is the data in your post the result of doing `$array |ConvertFrom-Json`?

Comment: Yes  @Mathias R, jessen

Comment: What property decides if an item is the same as another? `UserPrincipalName` perhaps or a combination of several properties?

Comment: we can consider "UserPrincipalName" as property to check the uniqueness  @Theo

Comment: Not to undermine anyone but what did you try @Sandeep? Where is your piece of code ? Where is your effort ?

Comment: Use the UPN to capture the SPN and sort unique on that.  Can't have duplicate SPN's afaik.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sort-Object -Unique` to sort the data according to some property and only keep objects with distinct values (for that property):

```
$sortedUnique = $array |Sort-Object UserPrincipalName -Unique
```

Comment: It is giving only the 1st object

Comment: @Sandeep Does `$array` contain the json strings, or the parsed objects?

Comment: This will not work because PSCustomObject does not implement IComparable. What probably happens under the hood is that all elements are determined to be the same - PSCustomObject - and so you get only a single one - the first.

Comment: @user2962533 we're not comparing objects, we're comparing the string values stored in the `UserPrincipalName` property on each object - which are comparable :)